# How do I add int. to char and string to get "abc" in the output? (For Java)

Tags: java

So I was given this formatted problem and told to fix the format in order to get the output.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
char p = 'a';
String s = "c"
```

The format is
(p + x + p + y + s)

And I'm supposed to change this (as long as I use x,y,p,s) to make the output be "abc."

How do I do this? The farthest I've gotten is that

```
System.out.println(p=(char)((int)p+x));
```

And that makes the output "a".

What do I do? Help please! I'm a very new programmer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MadProgrammer That still won't work, because `char + char` is integer math. You must force string concatenation, either by converting the first char to a string, or use a builder: `new StringBuilder().append(p + x).append(p + y).append(s).toString()`

Comment: It's a cheat, but something like `String.format("%c%c%s", p + x, p + y, s)` seems to work

Comment: I don't know what weird rules you have to follow, but: `((char) (p + x) + ((char) (p + y) + s))`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following which works:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
char p = 'a';
String s = "c";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append((char)((int)p+x)).append((char)((int)p+y)).append(s);
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

It prints: `abc`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(p + String.valueOf((char)(p+y)) + s);
```

Thanks for asking this question, I probably would have never known that String constructor doesn't take only a single character as a parameter.

For clarity:

String.valueOf() returns the character p+y as a String.

When you use + between all the three, they get concatenated.

Edit- A note on what you were doing with your code is that in the line:

```
System.out.println(p=(char)((int)p+x));
```

You here are overwriting the value of character variable `p` which already stores the value of character `'a'` with the value of `p+x`. Here, `x` is 0 so it will be added to the ASCII value of character stored in p, i.e `'a'` and results in the same.

Another note is that even if `x` was something else other than 0, you didn't have to first type cast into `(int)`, you could have directly type casted it into `(char)`. And since the variable where you are storing that operation is a character itself, you don't need any type casting at all!